# I have installed a plugin named JIVE in the Eclipse software. it prompts that the source code is not available when i use it

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, visualizer, jive

I have installed a plugin named JIVE in the Eclipse software. It can generate object diagrams and sequence diagrams based on Java source code and supports features like rollback and filtering. However, when I right-click on the sequence diagram and choose "jump to source", it prompts that the source code is not available. What could be causing this?
[See the picture for details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGlIW.png)

I hope that when I click to jump, the cursor in the source code window on the left will be on the corresponding source code, which will facilitate my debugging of complex framework code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.